# Re-use "common variables" in terraform for Lambda environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Let's say I have multiple lambda's with their own specific env vars but also share a list of common env vars, how can I define the common env vars in one location and use "spread" that into the lambda's env var definition?

In Javascript, you could use the spread operator, so something like this

```
COMMON_VARS = {
  COMMON_VAR_1 = var.common_var_1
  COMMON_VAR_2 = var.common_var_2
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_1" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = {
      LAMBDA_VAR_1      = var.lambda_var_1
      ...COMMON_VARS
    }
  }
  ...
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_2" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = {
      LAMBDA_VAR_2      = var.lambda_var_2
      ...COMMON_VARS
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that all the `var.*` variables will be defined in `variable` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [merge](https://search.brave.com/search?q=terraform+merge) to combine common and new variables:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_1" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = merge(var.COMMON_VARS, {
      LAMBDA_VAR_1      = var.lambda_var_1
    })
  }
  ...
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_2" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = merge(var.COMMON_VARS, {
      LAMBDA_VAR_2      = var.lambda_var_2
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would I use a `type = "map"` for the common vars?

Comment: @PGT Yes, it can be `map` or you don't have to explicitly specify type if you don't want.